# FB.Init fails when there's no internet connection in Unity Facebook SDK

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

Due to the nature of my app, I need to call FB.Init as soon as possible.

```
FB.Init(onInitDelegate);
```

This works great all the time except for the case when there is no internet connection. In this case, the onInitDelegate won't be called and I am left with a hanging app

I could create a timeout for the init, but I would rather have an error callback, or a try-catch alternative. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add the FB Init to a coroutine and have it set a small wait in there,

as an example:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Example: MonoBehaviour {

    private bool attemptingConnection = false;
    private bool socaillyConnected = false;
    private float trySocialCallAgain = 0.0f;

    IEnumerator WaitAndInit() {
        attemptingConnection = true;
        // Make sure the level is fully loaded.
        while(Application.isLoadingLevel()) { }
        // give it just a second.
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        try {
          FB.Init(onInitDelegate);
          sociallyConnected = true;
        } catch {
          Debug.Log("Unable to connect to facebook");
          trySocialCallAgain = Time.time + 10;
        }
        attemptingConnection = true;
    }

    void Start() {
        //StartCoroutine(WaitAndInit());
    }

    void LateUpdate() {
        if(!(sociallyConnected) && (!attemptingConnection )) {
           if(Time.time > trySocialCallAgain) {
              StartCoroutine(WaitAndInit());
           }
        }
    }
}
```

This will try to make a connection in the background, if no connection could be made it will wait 10 seconds and try again.

This will wait until the application is fully loaded and then wait an additional second just to make sure, not sure, why i added that part, i guess you could take that out.
after the application starts and attempt to connect to facebook, if not it will throw a catch exception.

hope that helped.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar, since I cannot find a way to retrieve the error from facebook sdk. I am starting a timeout of 5 seconds and make a call to one of my game servers. If the game server replies, it means that there is an internet connection and I only start the FB.Init in that case.

Comment: me too. I'm surprised that Facebook does not care this sdk much.